# While form is processing show spinner gif

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, gif

I have a form that takes about 15 seconds to process and would like to show a spinner gif once the form is submitted and remove it once the form is complete. Also the form redirects to a new page and was wondering what the best method is to accomplish this? Should I be submitting this form with Ajax? Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it via ajax.. Use this [ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) and [ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) to show and hide your animation while ajax request is processing.

Comment: Awesome thanks, so I would just submit the form with Ajax and then those Ajax start and stop functions will run when ever I process Ajax?

Comment: Yes, those functions will be called with every ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do it via Ajax. Put up an animated gif when the ajax call is kicked off, and remove it when the Ajax callback returns

Ex:

//add spinner gif

//make ajax request

//process call back and remove spinner

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what I was thinking but it just kind of seems a bit of a waste to have to use Ajax as the form is being redirected after anyways.